# 'SIGPIPE': undeclared identifier in luasocket-2.0.2

Tags: c, lua, luasocket

I am trying to compile [luasocket-2.0.2](http://files.luaforge.net/releases/luasocket/luasocket) (or: [luasocket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html)) but as I try to do so, some macros appear to be undefined. Namely:

```
identifier "SIGPIPE" is undefined
identifier "F_GETFL" is undefined
identifier "O_NONBLOCK" is undefined
identifier "F_SETFL" is undefined
```

If I google this I see that signal.h has to be included for this. I didn't change the code or anything and as you'd expect, the headers are included:

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <signal.h>

#include "socket.h"
```

Not quite sure what I am missing here.

I try to compile this for Windows.

Compiler Flags:

```
/GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /I"E:\git\luasocket-2.0.2\../luaext-linker/include" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"mime\Debug\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "MIME_EXPORTS" /D "MIME_API=__declspec(dllexport)" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /Fa"mime\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"mime\Debug\" /Fp"mime\Debug\mime.pch"
```

The errors occur in **usocket.c** of the socket project:

```
"SIGPIPE" is undefined  socket  e:\git\luasocket-2.0.2\src\usocket.c    80
...
```

Comment: Describe your problem more detail. In what way are you trying to build it, used compiler flags, exact error message along with source file name, etc.

Comment: @Sergio I've added the requested information. If there is more I can add please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `usocket.c` is a Unix-specific source.

```
/*=========================================================================*\
* Socket compatibilization module for Unix
* LuaSocket toolkit
```

You shouldn't try to include it into Win-targeted builds (unless you are using Cygwin). Also `socket.vcxproj` doesn't mention this file in the sourceset. That confirms previous suggestion.

If you've decided to built it via `win32.cmd` script - correct path to prefix, since script uses hardcoded one:

```
make LUAPREFIX_win32='c:\cygwin\home\diego\vc12' LUAV=5.1 PLAT=win32 LUALIBNAME_win32=lualib.lib PLATFORM_win32=Debug install-both
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's in your compile flags. I can't look on your system from here, but the `/I` flags are where it is happening, and the issue is that `signal.h` isn't in any of those directories.

This is probably some kind of bug in the package itself. Report this to the developers, and in the meantime, find `signal.h` and copy it into one of the include directories as a workaround.

Comment: If some of requested headers is missed - built process stops much earlier, and error message tells about missed header, not about undeclared identifiers.